# How to write a XSD

Tags: web-services, rest, xsd, cxf

I do not know how to write xsd for this request down.

Method POST

Request Parameters

all required

Tag Name

```
publicId type String 
publicIdType type String
actorType type String
startDate type Date
endDate   type Date
```

example

```
<actor>
  <actorPublicId>2424252</actorPublicId>
  <actorPublicIdType>1341416</actorPublicIdType>
  <actorType>test</actorType>
  <startDate>2014-03-10T22:34:34.999+2:00</startDate>
  <endDate>2014-03-10T22:34:34.999+2:00</endDate>
</actor>
```

Comment: have you solved this issue? if yes, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XSD is ..

```
<xs:schema 
   attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
   elementFormDefault="qualified" 
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   targetNamespace="yourNamespace" 
    xmlns:pref="yourNamespace">

    <xs:element name="actor" type="pref:actor"/>
    <xs:complexType name="actor">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="actorPublicId"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="actorPublicIdType"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="actorType"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:dateTime" name="startDate"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:dateTime" name="endDate"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```